# Handling Instagram 'geography' objects using Instagram Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, node.js

I'm trying to build something similar to http://demo.instagram.com ([Real-time Photo Updates](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/)) using the 
[Instagram Ruby Gem](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem). I'm kind of stuck on how to handle realtime object updates 
received over the callback URL.

In Node.js, this is done the following way: 
https://gist.github.com/909822

How do I do this using `Instagram.process_subscription()`, resp. the Instagram Ruby Gem?

There is an [example on how to handle a 'user media change' with the Gem on Github](https://%20%20github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/blob/master/lib/instagram/%20%20client/subscriptions.rb), but I can't figure out how to convert this into a 'geography media change'.

Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I've found it out myself:

```
  Instagram.process_subscription(request.body.string) do |handler| 
    handler.on_geography_changed do |object_id| 
      # object_id tells you what subscribed geography-object has been updated
    end 
  end
```